# Set variables depending on Ansible facts

Tags: ansible

Afternoon,

I am writing playbook for to run basic setup of Linux hosts across multiple domains. Let’s say we have domains aaa.com, bbb.com and ccc.com.
Each domain has different DNS, NTP, etc.
What I am doing is basically using set_fact module in main.yml -

```
- name: Set aaa.com variables
  set_fact:
    ntp1: 10.1.1.10
    ntp2: 10.1.1.11
  when: ansible_domain == 'aaa.com' 

 - name: Set bbb.com variables
  set_fact:
    ntp1: 10.2.1.10
    ntp2: 10.2.1.11
  when: ansible_domain == 'bbb.com'

 - name: Set ccc.com variables
  set_fact:
    ntp1: 10.3.1.10
    ntp2: 10.3.1.11
  when: ansible_domain == 'ccc.com'
```

Afterwards I am using templates to call variables.

All works well but I have a feeling that this can be solved better.
What is the best approach for this case?
And how I can set default variable if domain is not defined on the list?

Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data into a dictionary. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_domains:
      aaa.com:
        ntp1: 10.1.1.10
        ntp2: 10.1.1.11
      bbb.com:
        ntp1: 10.2.1.10
        ntp2: 10.2.1.11
      ccc.com:
        ntp1: 10.3.1.10
        ntp2: 10.3.1.11
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "domain: {{ item }}
              ntp1: {{ my_domains[item].ntp1 }}
              ntp2: {{ my_domains[item].ntp2 }}"
      loop: "{{ my_domains.keys()|list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "msg": "domain: aaa.com ntp1: 10.1.1.10 ntp2: 10.1.1.11"
    "msg": "domain: bbb.com ntp1: 10.2.1.10 ntp2: 10.2.1.11"
    "msg": "domain: ccc.com ntp1: 10.3.1.10 ntp2: 10.3.1.11"
```

---

Then, the task below simplifies the declaration of the variables

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ntp1: "{{ my_domains[ansible_domain].ntp1 }}"
        ntp2: "{{ my_domains[ansible_domain].ntp2 }}"
```

---

The code can be further simplified by putting the data into the *group_vars*. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml 
my_domains:
  aaa.com:
    ntp1: 10.1.1.10
    ntp2: 10.1.1.11
  bbb.com:
    ntp1: 10.2.1.10
    ntp2: 10.2.1.11
  ccc.com:
    ntp1: 10.3.1.10
    ntp2: 10.3.1.11
ntp1: "{{ my_domains[ansible_domain].ntp1 }}"
ntp2: "{{ my_domains[ansible_domain].ntp2 }}"
```

Then the inventory (you will probably let Ansible discover *ansible_domain*)

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
srv1.aaa.com ansible_domain=aaa.com
srv1.bbb.com ansible_domain=bbb.com
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: srv1.aaa.com,srv1.bbb.com
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ntp1 }} {{ ntp2 }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [srv1.aaa.com] => {
    "msg": "10.1.1.10 10.1.1.11"

ok: [srv1.bbb.com] => {
    "msg": "10.2.1.10 10.2.1.11"
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad! Like the idea with putting definition in group_vars.